# Change Button XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabitem

I have a tab control in which I am adding tab items programmatically. I want to have a close button with each tab item. On googling I found below XAML code for it:

```
<Button Content="X" Cursor="Hand" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        Focusable="False" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" 
        FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

Now, I am converting this code into equivalent C# code and struggling with some of the properties. Below given is the code which I have till now.

```
var CloseButton = new Button()
{
     Content = "X",
     Focusable = false,
     FontFamily = FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier"),
     FontSize = 9,
     Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0),
     Width = 16,
     Height = 16
};
```

I want help with properties like Cursor, DockPanel.Dock. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Take look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx the only property that you need and I have not found is DockPanel.Dock. I think you are using System.Windows.Forms.Button instead of System.Windows.Controls.Button

Comment: DockPanel.Dock can be handled through a DockPanel object. See usage in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference

Comment: And as YashTD wrote the Dock Panel can be handeled in this way DockPanel.SetDock(CONTROL_NAME, Dock.Right);

Comment: @S.Petrosov I F12ed it and it took me to System.Windows.Controls.Button namespace :)

Comment: Yes true. Sorry for the mistake. I have a VM and it has CloseCommand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cursors are a fairly standard set of types. There are static classes out there that give you access to many of them.  Use the `Cursors` class to get the `Hand`.

`DockPanel.Dock` is an attached property, it's not a property of the button control.  You have to use the property setters for that dependency object or other convenience methods if available.

```
var button = new Button
{
    Content = "X",
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
    Focusable = false,
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier"),
    FontSize = 9,
    Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0),
    Width = 16,
    Height = 16
};
// this is how the framework typically sets values on objects
button.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Right);
// or using the convenience method provided by the owning `DockPanel`
DockPanel.SetDock(button, Dock.Right);
```

Then to set the bindings, create the appropriate binding object and pass it to the element's `SetBinding` method:

```
button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("DataContext.CloseCommand")
{
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource { AncestorType = typeof(TabControl) },
});
button.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("Header"));
```

Comment: Getting error on button.SetValue : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' is not a valid value for property 'Command'.

Comment: @NareshRavlani It should be SetBinding instead of SetValue.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have VM and CloseCommand. I think I need some coffee :P

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted ur answer, I got everything except close command. And now I have different implementation so I can not have close command anymore. I need to find some other way to close the tab. Any idea for it? Maybe something I can do with Click event of Button?

Comment: Thanks @Clemens for tidying it up. It's been a long time since I last had to programmatically do anything in WPF so a little rusty. And especially appreciated since I was just about to go to bed. :)

Comment: @NareshRavlani: that would be for another question and not for here in comments. If you needed the button to do something else, either bind to a different command that does what you need it to do or change the implementation of that command.